# What difference it makes if I use OR statements instead of IN in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

What difference it makes if I use, `winner IN ('Subject1','Subject2');` & `winner='Subject1' OR winner='Subject2';`

Queries for the table 17 in the below link:

https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-retrieve-from-table.php#SQLEDITOR

Comment: The expression reads different. Other than that: None.

Comment: I am not familiar with MySQL, but with IN you can probably use a table, e.g. `winner IN (SELECT columnX FROM tableY WHERE somePredicate)`.

Comment: Use IN, because 1) Less characters to type. 2) Reduce risk of AND/OR issues when also having other conditions.

Answer (score 2):

For lists with two elements it doesn't make a difference.

However, MySQL optimizes `IN` when the list consists of constant expressions.  It basically sorts them and does a binary search through the list.  This can be a considerable savings with longer lists.  As the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) explains:

> If all values are constants, they are evaluated according to the type
>   of expr and sorted. The search for the item then is done using a
>   binary search. This means IN is very quick if the IN value list
>   consists entirely of constants.

In general, `IN` is safer and does a better job of capturing the column you want.  It is very easy to take conditions like this:

```
where winner = 'Subject1' OR winner = 'Subject2'
```

and add another condition:

```
where winner = 'Subject1' or winner = 'Subject2' and
      foo = 'bar'
```

and this logic is probably not longer what you really want -- because it really means:

```
where winner = 'Subject1' or
      (winner = 'Subject2' and foo = 'bar')
```

This doesn't happen with `IN`:

```
where winner in ('Subject1', 'Subject2') and
      foo = 'bar'
```

Comment: Dont believe your statement `and the logic is not longer what you really want.` is very clear. Had to read it myself a couple of times to understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

If there's an index on the column in question, `IN` vastly out-performs `OR`. Experience has shown me that the db consistently doesn't use the index when there's an `OR` on the column.

If there's *no* index on the column in question, `IN` out-performs `OR` if the list is longer than about 5 (it's faster to do a few serial comparisons than traverse a small BTree of values, which is what the DB turns the list into for execution).

`IN` is also preferred for readability and avoiding SQL's operator precedence trap if brackets are omitted, ie `x = a or x = b and c = d` is parsed as `x = a or (x = b and c = d)` instead of the (perhaps) expected `(x = a or x = b) and c = d`.

Answer (score 0):

Careful when using NOT:

```
select col1 from
(
select 1 as col1
union all
select 2 as col1
union all
select 3 as col1
union all
select 4 as col1
)x
where x.col1 NOT IN (2,3,4) ;
----------
col1
1
```

However

```
select col1 from
(
select 1 as col1
union all
select 2 as col1
union all
select 3 as col1
union all
select 4 as col1
)x
where x.col1 != 2 OR x.col1 != 3 OR x.col1 != 4 ;

---
col1
1
2
3
4
```